# Defining scope in optimizely

Tags: angularjs, optimizely

I am reading through some of the docs for optimizely and saw an interesting value that they add to scope.  I am not sure that I fully understand it.

Here is the function in their docs

```
 function(activate, options) {
   var scope = window.angular.element('body').scope();
   scope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event, next, current) {
     if (next.indexOf('/productPage') != -1) {
       if (!options.isActive) {
         activate();
       }
     }
   });
 }
```

I do not completely follow  **var scope**  Is this similar to a *** $rootscope *** ?

I know you can get the value of an associated scope by doing this

```
angular.element($0).scope()
```

I see window and want to assume this is beyond a local scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is equal to current application's `$rootScope` as long as it was bootstrapped with `body` element, and there are no directives on `body` that have their own scopes. As long as the app was bootstrapped with `body` or `html`, it will work for current piece of code because `$locationChangeSuccess` is broadcasted to all scopes.

For the case when [debugging data](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production#disabling-debug-data) is enabled the failproof methods are

```
var root = angular.element(document.querySelector('.ng-scope')).scope().$root;
```

and

```
var root = angular.element(document.querySelector('.ng-scope')).injector().get('$rootScope');
```